# Sharepoint XML export to Excel - can you convert?

Tags: sharepoint-server, excel, xml

There are some data stored in sharepoint List which uses XML as the source. I used javascript to make it look good on sharepoint BUT when exporting to Excel - obviously - it does not copy the format and is left with the xml source instead.

Example (this is just one section of a long list):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RepeaterData><Version /><Items><Item><Method type="System.String">Cash</Method><Amount type="System.Double">100</Amount><Rate type="System.Double">0</Rate><planRates type="System.String">0</planRates><planRatesValue type="System.Decimal">100.00</planRatesValue><calculateTotalAmount type="System.Decimal">100.00</calculateTotalAmount><Returned type="System.Double">84.75</Returned><ReturnedRate type="System.Decimal">0.00</ReturnedRate><TotalRemaining type="System.Decimal">15.25</TotalRemaining><varCurrency type="System.String">GBP - Sterling</varCurrency><SelectCurrency type="System.String">1</SelectCurrency></Item><Item><Method type="System.String">Cash</Method><Amount type="System.Double">500</Amount><Rate type="System.Double">0.883</Rate><planRates type="System.String">0.9</planRates><planRatesValue type="System.Decimal">450.00</planRatesValue><calculateTotalAmount type="System.Decimal">441.50</calculateTotalAmount><Returned type="System.Double">423.45</Returned><ReturnedRate type="System.Decimal">373.91</ReturnedRate><TotalRemaining type="System.Decimal">67.59</TotalRemaining><varCurrency type="System.String">EUR - Euro</varCurrency><SelectCurrency type="System.String">2</SelectCurrency></Item></Items></RepeaterData>
```

Can the above be formatted back to cells in Excel ? 
if so, is there a comfortable method in doing so?

Update: screenshot

Notice that the [Item] [Amount] etc appear twice cos there are 2 entries.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 1**: With the image provided, it's not possible to make it as you want. Please, read my last comment.

Well, you could create calculated columns in your list. These calculated columns would get data from each column, so, using this formula:

```
=MID([Method], FIND(">", [Method], 1)-1, FIND("<", [Method], 1)-1)
```

In this way, you could get the text between tags, because `MID` function combined with `FIND` could get the text between tags. In that example you would get the text from <*Method*> tag.

So, once you have the correct text en each calculated column, you can create a view in that list with these calculated columns, and when you export you will see the correct columns in the Excel.

Resources:

- [FIND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-function-06213f91-b5be-4544-8b0b-2fd5a775436f) function.
- [MID](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mid-function-2eba57be-0c05-4bdc-bf81-5ecf4421eb8a) function.

Comment: the  [Method works but not everything else ... also I noticed this won't show more than 1 entry. Meaning the [Amount] can appear twice due to showing different currency & amount etc.

Comment: If it works for [Method], then it should work for other columns. Are you sure that you have one column for each tag (Method, Amount, Rate...) and one entry for each <Item>? Please explain more.

Comment: i have attached a screenshot in my post. In that case there are 2 entries with different amounts,  rates etc. As you can see, the METHOD column has shown only CASH although in that instance the Method appears twice for instance ... not sure if I am clear

Comment: Thank you for screenshot. Of course what I said it's not going to work, because formulas in calculated columns are not recursive, I mean, it's not going to navigate through all that XML. You may try to insert each XML tag in a different column and one entry per Item in the list, then what I said it will work.

Comment: @Bucki, please mark the answer as correct answer if it was useful. Thanks

Comment: I can mark it as useful if that will give you points but it does not fully resolve my problem. Which of course does involve more coding etc ... whereby I must give up as this is not my best skill set.

Comment: I would be thankful if you marked as useful. Initially I thought that you had each XML tag in each column, but, as I told, it's not going to work with that format. As a partial solution, you may try searching a "xml to excel" solution. So, if you achieve to get in each Excel column each XML tag, you will then be able to copy from Excel and paste it directly in the SharePoint list by using Edit mode (using IE). So, you will have the needed format. Hope it helps :)

Comment: marked as useful :) and I also searched for XML to Excel but not found anything that is a straight forward thing to do ... apart from coding etc. which is far from what I can do :/ cheers for ur input though.

Answer (score 0):

This post is a bit vague, but assuming all your data has the same tags and you successfully managed to export the entire xml record as a single text cell in excel, you can extract the data into a series of calculated columns using the Left, Mid, Right & Len functions within excel.

https://spreadsheeto.com/text-functions/

Note that this will not conserve your cell type formatting (string/ float/ double e.t.c) but if you're wily you can set that value once and let calculated columns take care of the rest.

Alternatively you could try copy directly from the webpage after it had been reformatted using js and paste it directly into excel. If the formatting creates issues you could try paste into a text editor first.

A more manual method would be to export the spreadsheet as a csv and use an xml tag stripping algorithm or simply use find & replace in a text editor like notepad++ to remove the tags yourself indivdually from each record.

Comment: sorry about my question being vague but was not sure how to explain in other words. Basically, for each entry in SharePoint List there is an individual XML code. when exporting the list into excel it takes all cells but then end up with the XML in the particular cells.

Comment: copy pasting from nice looking format, does not work :/ as this is what I tried first thing lol. The exporting works fine from SP but when it uses the XML it does make it difficult to read to excel :(

Comment: If you're trying to import raw xml use an xml map or try importing xml according to Microsoft guidelines https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-XML-data-6eca3906-d6c9-4f0d-b911-c736da817fa4

Comment: Doe, there is an XML source for each entry which starts with "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>" just imagine the code in my question is repeated many times ... i tried to import it that way via MAPPing in Excel but it does not work.

Comment: never mind ... it is way more complicated as I initially thought and besides that, I am not a coder nor a developer. I hoped for some kind of build in option within excel or something ..... thanks for your suggestions though.

Comment: What format is your exported file?

Comment: It shouldn't be that complicated. If all else fails I would just open the file with notepad++ and find and replace the <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> header. That should allow you to import into excel

Comment: replace the header with what instead?? Just to be clear, the SharePoint creates the XML code in a multiple textfield for each entry. Meaning, Entry 1 and Entry 2 haave same XML source but only the figures e.g. the amount differs. It is a list which keeps track of who has requested any money and how much they returned etc.